# Is there any tool for Ethereum which can convert smart contract into REST API similar to hyperledger fabric?

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-development, hyperledger-fabric

In Hyperledger Fabric, REST API can be created for chain code/smart contract using composer-rest-server.
Is there any tool which can do the same for Ethereum Smart Contract?

So that any front developer only call these APIs.
I know about web3 library.
I am just asking is it possible for etherum or not?
can we use compiled smart contract JSON file as a REST API?

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a restful api which can read smart contracts or build the data to execute smart contracts, have a look at https://cinder.cloud/ethereum-contract-api

Answer (score -2):

This might be what you're looking for: 
https://github.com/blockapps/blockapps-rest

Comment: The purpose is simple that smart contract gives rest API directly instead of going through the web3.

Comment: just edited my answer. Hope it helps

Comment: make sure to marke the answer as correct if you found it useful=)

Comment: It is for blockapps means you have build everything in strato then you can use it.

Comment: Then Im afraid the answer to your question is no